# Will Funduino Joystick Shield work on a Mega?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, wifi

I am trying to get a Funduino Joystick Shield working with an Arduino Mega and I need to use the WiFi capability. The specs I have found for the Funduino (see https://protosupplies.com/product/funduino-joystick-shield-v1-a/) use the standard UNO pins for the RF24: 9..13, The Mega uses pins in the high 40s for this interface. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: The MEGA pins needed to support the SPI interface used by the nRF24L01 are 50, 51 and 52. I can easily assign these pins in my software, but to physically connect them, I need to understand where the other end of the wires goes. Do I disconnect the WiFi header create a separate header? This seems like a bit of a kludge to me. It' easy to say, "Just use these pins..." but not so easy to determine HOW to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The shield will work on Mega, except of the SPI connection for the nRF24L01 connector. The shield expects SPI on pins 11, 12, 13 and Mega has them on 50, 51, 52. Other shields use the SPI pins on the ICSP header to have compatibility with different boards. This shield doesn't connect to the ICSP header.

You can wire the nRF24L01 to SPI pins on 50, 51, 52.

Comment: Thanks for the partial clarity. My question is now, HOW do I do this rewire given that the Funduino is sitting on top of the Mega, blocking all access to the pins.

Comment: Does the hardware automatically reroute the ports to pins 50-52 allowing me to just change how the nRF24 is addressed in  software?

Comment: @BobJones, as I see it, pins 50 to 53 for SPI and usual CS are not covered